# Converting between different accuracy/error metrics

Tags: r, statistics, classification, data-mining, data-science

I am trying to compare model accuracy between several different measurement metrics. For example, some citations use accuracy while other use error. That one is rather obvious, but there are lots of different metrics and I am not entirely sure how to compare some of them and not lose some of the individual metrics integrity. Or whether or not some can be compared at all. The list I have is:

Error Rate -
Mean Absolute Error -
Absolute Error -
Log-Loss -
Classification Accuracy -
Root Mean Squared Error -
Classification Error -
F-Measure -
Area Under Curve -
Mean Test Error -
Error Percentage -
Misclassification Error -
Test Error -
Mean Test Error

So my question is how to effectively convert between these, and if no direct conversion is possible, to compare and rank in a meaningful and accurate way.

Comment: @TerrnaceW  This is a question better suited for Cross Validated.  Stackoverflow is strictly for programming questions.

Comment: Agree. Voting off-topic/migrate.

Comment: @42- It's silly and discouraging that you would downvote me for an honest question. This is obviously a legitimate question - why would there be tags like "statistics", "classification" etc... These are not terms inherently associated with programming.

Comment: I didn't downvote; (although some two others else did and there's no way of identifying them.) As I explained, I voted to migrate. There is no code in your question and no data to do anything with. For a programming question you need to know what you want done, i.e. an algorithm, and you haven't gotten there yet. Do some more reading of the material in the SO Help Center.

Answer (score 1):

1. You usually cannot convert these metrics. They measure subtly different things. But *linear* error is not the same as *squared* error.
2. Winning in one metric does *not* mean winning on a different metric. Assume we want to summarize univariate data into a single number. The mean minimizes squared error, the median linear error - so they have different optimal solutions, and **depending on your evaluation measure, you may get different winners**.
3. Don't compare different articles. They *will* have used different preprocessing, features, feature selection, normalization, subset, different splits for crossvalidation etc.

Usually, comparing such numbers will not work.

You will have to re-run their experiments yourself, with exactly the same input and evaluation.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.